# Python- name ' ' is not defined

Tags: python

```
class Main:

    PROJECT_NAME = 'something'
    HOMEPAGE = 'something'
    DOMAIN_NAME = get_domain_name(HOMEPAGE)
    QUEUE_FILE = PROJECT_NAME + '/queue.txt'
    CRAWLED_FILE = PROJECT_NAME + '/crawled.txt'
    DATA_FILE = PROJECT_NAME + '/data.txt'
    NUMBER_OF_THREADS = 20
    queue = Queue()
    Spider(PROJECT_NAME, HOMEPAGE, DOMAIN_NAME)


    # Create worker threads (will die when main exits)
    def create_workers(self):
        for _ in range(self.NUMBER_OF_THREADS):
            t = self.threading.Thread(target=self.work)
            t.daemon = True
            t.start()


    # Do the next job in the queue
    def work(self):
        while True:
            url = self.queue.get()
            Spider.crawl_page(self.threading.current_thread().name, url)
            self.queue.task_done()


    # Each queued link is a new job
    def create_jobs(self):
        for link in self.file_to_set(self.QUEUE_FILE):
            self.queue.put(link)
        self.queue.join()
        self.crawl()


    # Check if there are items in the queue, if so crawl them
    def crawl(self):
        queued_links = self.file_to_set(self.QUEUE_FILE)
        if len(queued_links) > 0:
            print(str(len(queued_links)) + ' links in the queue')
            self.create_jobs()
create_workers()
crawl()
```

Above are my code. I have been receiving:

> NameError: name 'create_workers' is not defined and NameError: name 'crawl' is not defined.

Any help or suggestion for beginner here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must create an object of the class Main and through that object to use its methods, for this you must change:

```
create_workers()
crawl()
```

to:

```
m = Main()

m.create_workers()
m.crawl()
```